# Multiple required auth strategies for hapi.js?

Tags: facebook, session, authentication, cookies

I have a hapi server that saves login credentials to a session cookie using the node module 'hapi-auth-cookie'. I'm using 'bell' to allow certain features to be authenticated with Facebook.

In the handler for the Facebook authentication, how do I access session info from the session cookie while still being able to access information bell provides me from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

there's an [issue within the bell repository](https://github.com/hapijs/bell/issues/30#issuecomment-292102429) with a proposed solution to use `server.auth.test()`. Like this:

```
request.server.auth.test('strategy-name', request, (err, credentials) => {
  if (err) {
    // tested strategy didn't find a user
    return reply({ error: 'Cannot find your credentials' })
  }

  //there is a user :)
  return reply({ status: true, user: credentials.name })
})
```

Hope that helps and gives a direction :)